# Jquery :How to store textbox value clientside and display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The below code will update the display value enter by user in textbox when button clicked but in this code it will not preserve the previous value enter by user .

```
<h1>Type your comment below </h1>
<input id="txt_name" type="text" value="" />    
<button id="Get">Submit</button> 
<div id="textDiv"></div> - 
<div id="dateDiv"></div>
```

```js
jQuery(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
        var value = $("#txt_name").val(); 
        $("#textDiv").text(value);
        $("#dateDiv").text(new Date().toString());
    });
});
```

Now I want preserve all the value enter by user and when user will submit the button show both value previous as well as current.

How to achieve this ?

Can below code will help to preserve all the value

```
var $input = $('#inputId');    
$input.data('persist', $input.val() );
```

If yes how to display all value previous,current etc. when user click on button ?

Comment: for this you can use: var old_value = $('#textDiv').text(); var inputVal = $('#inputId').val(); var fullData = old_ value +' '+ inputval; $("#textDiv").text(fullData );

Comment: @YogeshShakya Let me tell you i need something like this which can get in Java with the help of List,ArrayList..like user enter anything in tetbox when submit button press add that value into List/ArrayList and display date with the help of that list.

Comment: Why you should do like that. It will display to them only know. After refreshing it will go.

Comment: You can simply use this: var ArrayList = [];

    $("button").click(function() {

        var value = $("#txt_name").val(); 

        var data = {date: new Date().toString(), text : value};

        ArrayList.push(data);
    });

Comment: @KajaMydeen Agree with you right now i cannt use db so its something excise for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got this right, this is what you need?

```
<h1>Type your comment below </h1>

<input id="txt_name" type="text" value="" />

<button id="Get">Submit</button> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
      var value = $("#txt_name").val(); 
      $("#section").prepend('<div class="textDiv">'+value+'</div>')
      $("#section").prepend('<div class="dateDiv">'+new Date().toString()+'</div>')
      $("#txt_name").val('');
    });
});
</script>

<!-- each time you press submit, a new line will be pushed here -->
<div id="section">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this is what i am looking ,cannt we get this  `.data()`

Comment: I lost it here, witch data you mean? Or where?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display only the previous and current value the user submitted and use the data function then:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var input = $("#txt_name").val(); 
    var previous = $("#textDiv").data('previous') || '';
    $("#textDiv").text(previous+input);
    $("#textDiv").data('previous',input);
    $("#dateDiv").text(new Date().toString());
});
```

If you want all the values and you want to store them, then I would create an array.  But you could always concatenate the string.

```
var arr = [];
$("button").click(function() {
    var input = $("#txt_name").val();
    arr.push(input);
    var previous = $("#textDiv").data('previous') || '';
    $("#textDiv").text(previous+input);
    $("#textDiv").data('previous',previous+input);
    $("#dateDiv").text(new Date().toString());
});
```

Without using `.data()` you can do this:

```
 $("button").click(function() {
    var input = $("#txt_name").val(); 
    $("#textDiv").text($("#textDiv").text()+input);
    $("#dateDiv").text(new Date().toString());
});
```

Comment: It will display only previous and current what if i need all the input value?

Comment: You could always store the values in a array @SubodhJoshi, i edited my awnser.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two separate divs for message and date, you can use a single div.

```
<h1>Type your comment below </h1>
<input id="txt_name" type="text" value="" />
<button id="Get">Submit</button>
<div id="msgDiv"></div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var preservedTxt = '';
  $("button").click(function() {
       var input = $("#txt_name").val();
       var date = new Date().toString();
       var msg = input + ' - ' + date;

       preservedTxt = preservedTxt + '<br>' + msg;

       $('#msgDiv').html(preservedTxt);
   });
});
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/p2pcwj2f/

Answer (score 0):

Storing values in array will help

```
    jQuery(function(){
var name=[];
var time=[];
    $("button").click(function() {
        var value = $("#txt_name").val(); 
        name.push(value);
        $("#textDiv").text(name);
        time.push(new Date().toString())
        $("#dateDiv").text(time);

    });
});
```